# Is there an elixir guard clause for iodata

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have a function that can take any io_data and nothing else, because it's going to send it over a http connection. At the moment I have an `is_binary` guard clause but this is too restrictive.

So is there a guard clause that checks if something is io_data or not?

e.g.

```
def do_the_stuff(content) when is_iodata(content) do
  # e.g.
  IO.puts(content)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific guard for that. Usually libraries use 
`when is_binary(iodata) or is_list(iodata)`

Comment: what if you have a list of maps `[%{}]` won't that pass and not be io_data?

Comment: Yes, it will. Also `is_binary(IoData)` won't work if it really _is_ a list of iodata-parts.

Comment: iodata is either an iolist or a binary, so is_binary(iodata) is a reasonable part of the guard clause. And yes - this can pass some false-positives, unfortunately this is not avoidable - elixir is not a statically typed language.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to catch invalid iodata terms in a guard.  `is_binary(content) or is_list(content)` is as close as you get.

If you want to check that the term is valid iodata before sending it, you can call `IO.iodata_length`, and check that it doesn't raise an error.  This is cheaper than converting the iodata to a binary, but does impose a cost that wasn't there before.  It might not be worth it, considering that the underlying library should raise an error if the data is invalid.